# why Blend Tree Automated Threshold not visible?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to create blend tree in a 2D game. When I choose a animation state and create a blend tree, the **threshold value** is disable so I cannot change the value. I searched web for the solution but get solution that I have to uncheck the automate threshold. I am unable to find checkbox or anything saying automate threshold. I am creating blend tree of **Blend Type 1D**. So how can I change the threshold value in Unity?

[image]

Comment: Well what are you blending with?  I only see 1 entry in your blend...

Comment: oh yes thats the issue thanks man